# differences between emmeans and ggplot2

Tags: r, mixed-model, ggplot2

I have the following mixed model

```
subject <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),each=12))
dep <- c(0.3763244126,0.2185001692,0.4191841742,0.9812978664,0.7429273683,0.6254715486,0.6200958213,0.4693300191,0.1779032899,0.0035873980,0.8821949826,0.4818012617,0.0008013437,0.6280700732,0.7126500814,0.4984349359,0.2457996449,0.3085733312,0.5903398243,0.3704800352,0.8215325437,0.0445236221,0.1849731791,0.3670945817,0.0022268933,0.1630332691,0.9734050406,0.2638539758,0.8550054496,0.9413964085,0.4548943471,0.0440815873,0.5222098769,0.6553600784,0.6853486744,0.0571945074,0.0923124240,0.6976544929,0.9257440316,0.5658967043,0.0636543627,0.1038574059,0.0662497468,0.9165439918,0.5200087291,0.9528015053,0.5347318368,0.1848373057,0.9948602219,0.9633110918,0.1482162909,0.9000614029,0.0898618386,0.7975253051,0.8334557347,0.8629821099,0.0001795699,0.2488384889,0.6382902598,0.1103540359,0.2199716354,0.2737281912,0.5694398067,0.7940423761,0.4906677457,0.5191186895,0.4770589883,0.2823238128,0.2458788699,0.6363522802,0.0306954833,0.6979198116)

f1 <- factor(rep(c("Female","Male","Female","Male","Male","Female"), each=12))
f2 <- c(0.098788608,0.934606288,0.145045152,0.841969882,0.498234471,0.562897249,0.359740488,0.082046687,0.183987342,0.082418820,0.173424633,0.799291329,0.041450568,0.686708743,0.352092230,0.823550310,0.650857094,0.331705763,0.659111451,0.745187314,0.066165065,0.870759966,0.154977488,0.031703774,0.065251788,0.707452073,0.564604314,0.224798417,0.656363138,0.047954841,0.500513114,0.923316812,0.706629266,0.561530974,0.670860932,0.414969178,0.709973062,0.452946384,0.187624344,0.278656351,0.562138433,0.655193272,0.014868182,0.518697012,0.414113229,0.273464316,0.844080831,0.962636550,0.952739605,0.728627219,0.761122951,0.309977150,0.755239042,0.208627128,0.481429897,0.376021223,0.753871400,0.164842337,0.921081061,0.859677311,0.600462073,0.119193708,0.276722102,0.854752641,0.962710853,0.956277061,0.228313179,0.920405764,0.001594131,0.104930433,0.241548888,0.549643015)
f3 <- factor(rep(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"),each=3, times=6))

data <- data.frame(sub=subject, dep=dep, f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3)

m <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data)
```

I use the `emmeans` package for post-hoc tests and `ggplot2` to plot the results. I'm finding some differences between the means calculated by `ggplot` and the means from `emmeans`

```
ggplot(aes(x=f3,y=dep,colour=f1),data=data) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")
emmeans(m, c("f1","f3"))
```

For example the mean for `male` in `day1` is `0.573`, but the `emmean` is `0.558`. Which value best represents my model then?

The data are balanced so I don't understand why the `emmeans` are different from the ordinary mean. Can someone help me?

Comment: "Estimated marginal means are based on a model – not directly on data." See here for more information: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html

Comment: Thanks @Stefan for your comment. Yes, you are right, I'd forgotten about that. But what exactly does that mean. Is it inaccurate to plot data like in my example with ggplot2 for mixed models? How can I visualize my mixed model effects by plotting the means of `day1:male`, `day1:female` etc without needing to calculate estimated marginal means?

Comment: I would run the model first, then calculate the estimated marginal means via the `emmeans()` function (incl. standard errors) and take those values for the `ggplot` call. Alternatively you can also plot `emmGrid` objects via the `emmip()` and `plot()` functions. See also here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html#plots

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I read those vignettes but I'm still confused why plotting with emmeans is a better representation of my model than simply plot the data. Do you have an opinion about that? I've read many posts in CV and most answers use functions like `fixef`, `coef` and `predict` to plot the data of a mixed model, although I'm not completely sure I understand how to do it.

Comment: Since you fitted a model to your data, you want to have means (or predictions) based on the model fit and not your raw data. `fixef` and `coef` will extract model-specific values. You can also use the `predict` function (and a bit more) to calculate emmeans yourself. Have a look at the answer here and the comments: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253756/manually-calculating-least-square-means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data are balanced, but one of your “factors,” namely `f2`, is actually a covariate, and your data are *not* balanced with respect to the values of that variable. If you were to take `f2` out of the model, I think the EMMs will match the ordinary marginal means, unless I’m overlooking something. But with `f2` in the model, the EMMs are like adjusted means in the analysis of covariance, based on predictions when `f2` is set at its mean value.

Another way to make them equal is to put `cov.adjust = list(f2~f1*f3)` in the `emmeans()` call. This sets it up so that predictions are made with `f2` set at its cell means for those two factors. Such EMMs are appropriate when `f2` is in the causal path, i.e. it is a mediating variable. That situation is discussed in the vignettes too, I think the one on messy data (could look it up in the vignette-topics index).